# How can I use goto in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, goto

I have some code that I absolutely must implement using `goto`. For example, I want to write a program like this:

```
start:
alert("RINSE");
alert("LATHER");
repeat: goto start
```

Is there a way to do that in Javascript?

Comment: goto would be conviniend for compiled javascript. I've a JVM written in JavaScript. It would be much performanter and shorter with goto statement.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Absolutely! There is a project called [Summer of Goto](https://alexsexton.com/blog/2009/07/goto-dot-js/) that allows you use JavaScript at its fullest potential and will revolutionize the way you can write your code.

This JavaScript preprocessing tool allows you to create a label and then goto it using this syntax:

```
[lbl] <label-name>
goto <label-name>
```

For example, the example in the question can be written as follows:

```
[lbl] start:
alert("LATHER");
alert("RINSE");
[lbl] repeat: goto start;
```

Note that you are not just limited to simple trivial programs like an endless `LATHER` `RINSE` repeat cycle—the possibilities afforded by `goto` are endless and you can even make a `Hello, world!` message to the JavaScript console 538 times, like this:

```
var i = 0;
[lbl] start:
console.log("Hello, world!");
i++;
if(i < 538) goto start;
```

[You can read more about how goto is implemented](http://alexsexton.com/?p=11), but basically, it does some JavaScript preprocessing that takes advantage of the fact that you can simulate a goto with a [labelled `while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). So, when you write the "Hello, world!" program above, it gets translated to something like this:

```
var i = 0;
start: while(true) {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
  i++;
  if(i < 538) continue start;
  break;
}
```

There are some limitations to this preprocessing process, because while loops cannot stretch across multiple functions or blocks. That's not a big deal, though—I'm sure the benefits of being able to take advantage of `goto` in JavaScript will absolutely overwhelm you.

All above link that lead to goto.js library is ALL DEAD, here is links needed:

[goto.js (uncompressed)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160507105653/http://summerofgoto.com/js/goto.js) --- [parseScripts.js (uncompressed)](https://github.com/padolsey/parseScripts/blob/master/parseScripts.js)

From [Goto.js](https://alexsexton.com/blog/2009/07/goto-dot-js/):

Comment: @SurrealDreams It may be a joke, but it actually works. You can click the jsFiddle links and see that they actually work.

Comment: Oh, I believe that it's been implemented.  I mean to say that the project itself is a joke, they creators were being funny.

Comment: @PeterOlson No one cares if it actually works. The points is that it isn't actually useful. It isn't even javascript, it's pre-processing.

Comment: The article you linked to actually states it's a joke :)

Comment: @pimvdb I never denied that it was, I'm just saying that it's fully functional. Just because it's a joke doesn't mean you can't use it. ;)

Comment: @PeterOlson, But stackoverflow is intended to help people learn programming. The questions and answers should be useful to do that with. No one is being helped by this.

Comment: Peter, people [are taking this seriously](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14335353/447356) and actually using this joke for real. Can you please delete this and that site (assuming it's yours) for the love of JavaScript and programming?

Comment: @ShadowWizard This answer is already surrounded by plenty of disclaimers and people talking about why this shouldn't be used. I feel no shame in letting people who willfully ignore that face the consequences of doing so.

Comment: " Goto.js is a parsescripts hook to implement the classic 'goto' functionality into
  native javascript. If you are seriously considering using this script, please don't. " This cooment is in the goto script in the answer

Comment: I am developing the same attitude towards "magical" functions and over abstraction in code. It has similar effect to GOTO

Comment: It would be useful to have goto in javascript for some purposes, such as implementing client-side coroutines. Unfortunately the "joke" goto stuff linked is not very useful, being unable to jump forwards.

Comment: this might be really useful to act as break; continue; statements in functional programming loops/constructs

Comment: +1 for @AlexMills . Honestly, I think `goto` is probably under-utilized. It makes for some very nice error handling patterns. Heck, we use `switch`, which is `goto` in all but name, and nobody belly-aches.

Comment: I'd give you a double upvote if i could. You just made my day :D

Comment: Should still put a disclaimer at the top that the answer is a joke

Comment: @0x1mason, [Goto is way better than switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119103/632951). Bill Gates once observed that surprisingly programming hasn't gotten very much simpler or faster over the years. The reason for this is that earlier languages have goto,  and newer langauges though having new features, lack the simplicity and of goto. "*Goto-considered-harmful*" hereby considered harmful.

Comment: ECMAScript doesn't have such a statement.

Comment: How do you break out of nested loops without goto?

Comment: Can't believe I landed on this on the April Fool's day!!

Comment: Bonus points for any programmer who isn't afraid to try something just because everyone else screeches that it's bad and awful and wrong. 99% of the time `goto` is the worst solution, but once in a blue moon it's the simplest, most elegant solution. The look of senseless indignation on everyone else's face is just a bonus.

Comment: goto is necessary when writting super-performant code (mainly for drivers, which have relatively small code and processing is critical) - however, in many cases this is just renamed to "break" and "continue" and preventing jump out of functions calls.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard There are plenty of usecases where goto is completely necessary and the most obvious and readable construct.

Answer (score 156):

No. [They did not include that in ECMAScript:](https://es5.github.io/#x12.2)

> ECMAScript has no goto statement.

Comment: I was wondering if GOTO would be useful while debugging JavaScript. Afaik, only IE provides GOTO in its debugger... and I actually found a use-case for it, but I'm not sure if it could be useful generally... to jump around while debugging JavaScript. What do you think?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I'm not sure whether debugging with goto functionality is useful. Basically you'd be messing around with the code path in a way that would never happen without debugging anyway.

Comment: What a pity ... IMHO `goto` would fit just perfectly well into javascript's cocktail of stupid "features" :)

Comment: `goto` is a reserved keyword for future use, however. We can only hope :)

Comment: `goto` would be useful when you want to return from a nested function. For example, when using underscore.js, you provide an anonymous function when iterating over arrays. You can't return from inside such a function, so `goto end;` would be useful.

Comment: is this still true in 2015, will goto and labels not be supported

Comment: A nested function is merely a lexical construct. I've never seen a programming language that lets you, from one function, `goto` another. What would happen if you *returned* the nested function instead of calling directly into it, and then later when the nested function were invoked it tried to `goto` the outer function? What happens if you recurse through both functions and `goto` from the inner to the outer? *Which* invocation of the outer do you `goto`?

Comment: @Azmisov Yeah, just make `goto` syntactic sugar for `throw Error();`

Comment: @snarf — You've never seen Basic then? I take it you were not around when programming was young. Goto statements crossing function boundaries was all the rage. Actually, that was initially how subroutines were implements. #fwiw

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Have *you* ever seen BASIC? Old school BASIC doesn't have nested functions (or functions, period) and what happens when you `GOTO` from one routine to another is well-defined. If you try to pull the same stunt in a more modern language you're doing something conceptually broken and if the compiler were to try to oblige, all you would end up with is a corrupted stack. Oh, and being the sweet summer child I am, I learned to program in AppleSoft BASIC and 6502 ASM, #fwiw

Comment: ECMA should add `goto` keyword, sometimes it's important to goto the last block in function to do something the same in all logic branches; avoid duplicating code lines

Answer (score 50):

In classic JavaScript you need to use do-while loops to achieve this type of code. I presume you are maybe generating code for some other thing.

The way to do it, like for backending bytecode to JavaScript is to wrap every label target in a "labelled" do-while.

```
LABEL1: do {
  x = x + 2;
  ...
  // JUMP TO THE END OF THE DO-WHILE - A FORWARDS GOTO
  if (x < 100) break LABEL1;
  // JUMP TO THE START OF THE DO WHILE - A BACKWARDS GOTO...
  if (x < 100) continue LABEL1;
} while(0);
```

Every labelled do-while loop you use like this actually creates the two label points for the one label. One at the the top and one at the end of the loop. Jumping back uses continue and jumping forwards uses break.

```
// NORMAL CODE
MYLOOP:
  DoStuff();
  x = x + 1;
  if (x > 100) goto DONE_LOOP;
  GOTO MYLOOP;


// JAVASCRIPT STYLE
MYLOOP: do {
  DoStuff();
  x = x + 1;
  if (x > 100) break MYLOOP;
  continue MYLOOP;// Not necessary since you can just put do {} while (1) but it     illustrates
} while (0)
```

Unfortunately there is no other way to do it.

Normal Example Code:

```
while (x < 10 && Ok) {
  z = 0;
  while (z < 10) {
    if (!DoStuff()) {
      Ok = FALSE;
      break;
    }
    z++;
  }
  x++;
}
```

So say the code gets encoded to bytecodes so now you must put the bytecodes into JavaScript to simulate your backend for some purpose.

JavaScript style:

```
LOOP1: do {
  if (x >= 10) break LOOP1;
  if (!Ok) break LOOP1;
  z = 0;
  LOOP2: do {
    if (z >= 10) break LOOP2;
    if (!DoStuff()) {
      Ok = FALSE;
      break LOOP2;
    }
    z++;
  } while (1);// Note While (1) I can just skip saying continue LOOP2!
  x++;
  continue LOOP1;// Again can skip this line and just say do {} while (1)
} while(0)
```

So using this technique does the job fine for simple purposes. Other than that not much else you can do.

For normal Javacript you should not need to use goto ever, so you should probably avoid this technique here unless you are specificaly translating other style code to run on JavaScript. I assume that is how they get the Linux kernel to boot in JavaScript for example.

NOTE! This is all naive explanation. For proper Js backend of bytecodes also consider examining the loops before outputting the code. Many simple while loops can be detected as such and then you can rather use loops instead of goto.

Comment: `continue` in a `do ... while` loop continues *to the check condition*. The backwards `goto` here using `do ... while (0)` thus does not work. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.1

Comment: Doesn't work. I have to `let doLoop` for this to work. And main loop: `let doLoop = false; do { if(condition){ doLoop = true; continue; } } while (doLoop)` https://github.com/patarapolw/HanziLevelUp/blob/83eb0e3539a247a5cfc69d243e6a6e5ef373eda5/webapp/static/js/common.js#L90

Comment: In the first example, `continue` won't works, at end of code, The `} while(0);`  code should be change to: `break LABEL1; } while (true);`

Answer (score 32):

Actually, I see that ECMAScript (JavaScript) DOES INDEED have a goto statement. However, the JavaScript goto has two flavors!

The two JavaScript flavors of goto are called labeled continue and labeled break. There is no keyword "goto" in JavaScript. The goto is accomplished in JavaScript using the break and continue keywords.

And this is more or less explicitly stated on the w3schools website here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp.

I find the documentation of the labeled continue and labeled break somewhat awkwardly expressed.

The difference between the labeled continue and labeled break is where they may be used. The labeled continue can only be used inside a while loop. See w3schools for some more information.

===========

Another approach that will work is to have a giant while statement with a giant switch statement inside:

```
while (true)
{
    switch (goto_variable)
    {
        case 1:
            // some code
            goto_variable = 2
            break;
        case 2:
            goto_variable = 5   // case in etc. below
            break;
        case 3:
            goto_variable = 1
            break;

         etc. ...
    }

}
```

Comment: _"The labeled continue can only be used inside a while loop."_ - No, labelled `break` and `continue` may be used in `for` loops too. But they're really _not_ equivalent to `goto` given that they are locked into the structure of the related loop(s), as compared to `goto` which can of course - in languages that have it - go to anywhere.

Comment: What @nnnnnn said, they are not equivalent to `goto` because you must use a loop and the label must come before the `break`/`continue`.

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question, but since JavaScript is a moving target - it is possible in ES6 on implementation that support proper tail calls. On implementations with support for proper tail calls, you can have an unbounded number of active tail calls (i.e. tail calls doesn't "grow the stack").

A `goto` can be thought of as a tail call with no parameters.

The example:

```
start: alert("RINSE");
       alert("LATHER");
       goto start
```

can be written as

```
 function start() { alert("RINSE");
                    alert("LATHER");
                    return start() }
```

Here the call to `start` is in tail position, so there will be no stack overflows.

Here is a more complex example:

```
 label1:   A
           B
           if C goto label3
           D
 label3:   E
           goto label1
```

First, we split the source up into blocks. Each label indicates the start of a new block.

```
 Block1
     label1:   A
               B
               if C goto label3
               D

  Block2    
     label3:   E
               goto label1
```

We need to bind the blocks together using gotos. 
In the example the block E follows D, so we add a `goto label3` after D.

```
 Block1
     label1:   A
               B
               if C goto label2
               D
               goto label2

  Block2    
     label2:   E
               goto label1
```

Now each block becomes a function and each goto becomes a tail call.

```
 function label1() {
               A
               B
               if C then return( label2() )
               D
               return( label2() )
 }

 function label2() {
               E
               return( label1() )
 }
```

To start the program, use `label1()`.

The rewrite is purely mechanical and can thus be done with a macro system such as sweet.js if need be.

Comment: "it is possible in ES6 on implementation that support proper tail calls". AFAIK tail calls are disabled in all major browsers.

Comment: Safari supports proper tail calls, I believe. At the time the answer was given, it was possible to enable proper tail calls in Chrome via a command line switch. Let’s hope they reconsider - or at least begins to support explicitly marked tail calls.

Comment: Explicitly marked tail calls would probably make everyone happy.

Comment: @soegaard -One way to explicitly mark tail call would be "goto".

Comment: @CraigHicks
Except `goto` doesn't take arguments (in most languages). I think, the suggested syntax was: `return continue f(a,b,c)`. See Crowder's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788139/es6-tail-recursion-optimisation-stack-overflow   For the current status of tail calls in Node see:  https://javascript.plainenglish.io/tail-calls-in-javascript-will-there-be-a-comeback-63ac3a0523a5

Answer (score 15):

```
const
    start = 0,
    more = 1,
    pass = 2,
    loop = 3,
    skip = 4,
    done = 5;

var label = start;


while (true){
    var goTo = null;
    switch (label){
        case start:
            console.log('start');
        case more:
            console.log('more');
        case pass:
            console.log('pass');
        case loop:
            console.log('loop');
            goTo = pass; break;
        case skip:
            console.log('skip');
        case done:
            console.log('done');

    }
    if (goTo == null) break;
    label = goTo;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Sure, using the `switch` construct you can simulate `goto` in JavaScript. Unfortunately, the language doesn't provide `goto`, but this is a good enough of a replacement.

```
let counter = 10
function goto(newValue) {
  counter = newValue
}
while (true) {
  switch (counter) {
    case 10: alert("RINSE")
    case 20: alert("LATHER")
    case 30: goto(10); break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

How about a `for` loop?  Repeat as many times as you like.  Or a `while` loop, repeat until a condition is met.  There are control structures that will let you repeat code.  I remember `GOTO` in Basic... it made such bad code!  Modern programming languages give you better options that you can actually maintain.

Comment: The infinite production loop: Prototype, scratch, better prototype, scratch, better better prototype, scratch. **Maintenance is often a fallacy.**  Not many code needs to be maintained. Most code are rewritten, not maintained.

Comment: Code with deeply nested decision trees (such as parsing code) is most readably and maintainably expressed as a state machine, and all state machine implementations have the same structure, but goto is fastest.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way this can be done, but it needs to be planned carefully.
Take for example the following QBASIC program:

```
1 A = 1; B = 10;
10 print "A = ",A;
20 IF (A < B) THEN A = A + 1; GOTO 10
30 PRINT "That's the end."
```

Then create your JavaScript to initialize all variables first, followed by making an initial function call to start the ball rolling (we execute this initial function call at the end), and set up functions for every set of lines that you know will be executed in the one unit.

Follow this with the initial function call...

```
var a, b;
function fa(){
    a = 1;
    b = 10;
    fb();
}
function fb(){
    document.write("a = "+ a + "<br>");
    fc();
}
function fc(){
    if(a<b){
        a++;
        fb();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
    document.write("That's the end.<br>");
    }
}
fa();
```

The result in this instance is:

```
a = 1
a = 2
a = 3
a = 4
a = 5
a = 6
a = 7
a = 8
a = 9
a = 10
That's the end.
```

Comment: @JonHarrop is there a maximum stack size that JavaScript can handle before it stack overflows?

Comment: Yes and it seems to be extremely small. Much smaller than any other language I've ever used.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, I'd prefer not using GoTo for bad readability. To me, it's a bad excuse for programming simple iterative functions instead of having to program recursive functions, or even better (if things like a Stack Overflow is feared), their true iterative alternatives (which may sometimes be complex).

Something like this would do:

```
while(true) {
   alert("RINSE");
   alert("LATHER");
}
```

That right there is an infinite loop. The expression ("true") inside the parantheses of the while clause is what the Javascript engine will check for - and if the expression is true, it'll keep the loop running. Writing "true" here always evaluates to true, hence an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can simple use a function:

```
function hello() {
    alert("RINSE");
    alert("LATHER");
    hello();
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea as it will keep pushing the return address on the call stack until the system runs out of memory.

Comment: Indeed however the user will have CTRL-ALT-DELETEd long before from the endless modal RINSE-LATHER dialogues!

Answer (score 4):

To achieve goto-like functionality while keeping the call stack clean, I am using this method:

```
// in other languages:
// tag1:
// doSomething();
// tag2:
// doMoreThings();
// if (someCondition) goto tag1;
// if (otherCondition) goto tag2;

function tag1() {
    doSomething();
    setTimeout(tag2, 0); // optional, alternatively just tag2();
}

function tag2() {
    doMoreThings();
    if (someCondition) {
        setTimeout(tag1, 0); // those 2 lines
        return;              // imitate goto
    }
    if (otherCondition) {
        setTimeout(tag2, 0); // those 2 lines
        return;              // imitate goto
    }
    setTimeout(tag3, 0); // optional, alternatively just tag3();
}

// ...
```

Please note that this code is slow since the function calls are added to timeouts queue, which is evaluated later, in browser's update loop.

Please also note that you can pass arguments (using `setTimeout(func, 0, arg1, args...)` in browser newer than IE9, or `setTimeout(function(){func(arg1, args...)}, 0)` in older browsers.

AFAIK, you shouldn't ever run into a case that requires this method unless you need to pause a non-parallelable loop in an environment without async/await support.

Comment: Nasty. I love it. FWIW, that technique is called trampolining.

Comment: I can verify this works.  I'm manually transpiling some HP RPN with GTO statements which leads to deep recursion when implemented as function calls; the setTimeout() method shown above collapses the stack and recursion is no longer an issue. But it is much slower.

Oh, and I'm doing this in Node.js.

Answer (score 4):

```
// example of goto in javascript:

var i, j;
loop_1:
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //The first for statement is labeled "loop_1"
        loop_2:
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //The second for statement is labeled "loop_2"
                if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
                    continue loop_1;
                }
                console.log('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably read some JS tutorials like this **[one](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Control_Structures)**.

Not sure if `goto` exists in JS at all, but, either way, it encourages bad coding style and should be avoided.

You could do:

```
while ( some_condition ){
    alert('RINSE');
    alert('LATHER');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

goto begin and end of all parents closures

```
var foo=false;
var loop1=true;
LABEL1: do {var LABEL1GOTO=false;
    console.log("here be 2 times");
    if (foo==false){
        foo=true;
        LABEL1GOTO=true;continue LABEL1;// goto up
    }else{
        break LABEL1; //goto down
    }
    console.log("newer go here");
} while(LABEL1GOTO);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative way to achieve the same is to use the tail calls. But, we don’t have anything like that in JavaScript.
So generally, the goto is accomplished in JS using the below two keywords.
**break** and
**continue**,
reference: [Goto Statement in JavaScript](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-use-goto-statement-in-javascript/)

Here is an example:

```
var number = 0;
start_position: while(true) {
document.write("Anything you want to print");
number++;
if(number < 100) continue start_position;
break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my 2 cents at this since I found my own solution without loops or cluttering functions everywhere:

```
function rinseLatherSwitch(label) 
{
    function goto(to)
    {
        switch(to)
        {
            case "rinse": alert("RINSE"); return goto("lather");
            case "lather": alert("LATHER"); return goto("end");
            case "end": break;
        }
    }

    return goto(label);
}

rinseLatherSwitch("rinse");
```

This format has 3 benefits:

1. The structure of the code matches other languages switches with goto's (such as C#)
2. It is all self-contained within a single function so it won't clutter up any other code
3. It can handle any goto situation without extra work, not just endless loops (in fact the loop won't be endless due to stack overflow which in my books is a handy fail-safe)