# javascript: goto statement

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop, but in one condition, I want to skip some steps so that I have used `goto` statement...

```
for (var rows = 0; rows < result.data.length; rows++) {
  [lbl] topOfLoop:

  var row = result.data[rows]
  if (row[0] == "") {
    goto topOfLoop;
  }

  ----- // some code
}
```

Its not working ? Can anyone tell me, how it could be done ?

Comment: replace 'goto', with 'break', remove '[lbl]', place the 'topOfLoop:' label statement above the 'for' statement. Or, just use 'continue'.

Comment: There is no goto in javascript.

Comment: You definitely want to be using continue.

Comment: "go to" is a bad "engineering" practice, I have read somewhare I can't remember!

Comment: And no matter what language you are using if you EVER use 'goto' then your code is bad. goto is considered very bad (spagetti anyone?) https://www.google.com/search?q=why+goto+is+bad&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I wonder why you even tried that... of course it's not working because such a thing does not exist in JavaScript. What happened to reading tutorials?

Comment: ::but in continue keyword, the value of rows also will increment & i dont want to increment it...

Comment: @user1948530: But if `row` is not incremented, `result.data[rows][0]` will always be the same value and your `goto` statement will effectively be an infinite loop. Or is there other code in between?

Comment: @Felix it [began as a joke](http://summerofgoto.com/) but looks like people are actually using it. It was published [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9751229/447356). (If you ask me both that post here and that site should be removed)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: `:-O` I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure you want to use `continue;`:

```
for (var rows = 0; rows < result.data.length; rows++)  {
    var row = result.data[rows];
    if (row[0] == "") {
        continue;  
    }
    // some code
}
```

Comment: ::but in continue keyword, the value of rows also will increment & i dont want to increment it...

Comment: @user1948530 Im not sure what you are saying, care to explain?

Answer (score 4):

> i want to skip some steps so that i'v used goto statement...

Use [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) statement instead of goto

```
for (var rows = 0; rows < result.data.length; rows++) 
    {
        var row = result.data[rows]
        if (row[0] == "") 
        {
           continue;
        }
```

Comment: ::but in continue keyword, the value of rows also will increment & i dont want to increment it....

Comment: @user1948530, you can decrement the row and then use continue, but I am not sure why you want such thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement in your code;

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the
>   enclosing iteration statement in which it appears.

It is one of the Jump statements.

```
if (row[0] == "")
{
     continue;  
}
```

Comment: ::but in continue keyword, the value of rows also will increment & i dont want to increment it...

Comment: @user1948530 then decremant it with `rows--` after `continue`?