# does the ":" operator do anything outside of the ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, operators

there was a copy paste issue in some of our code the other day:

```js
      ...
      if (form.isValid()) {
         scope: me, form.updateRecord(record);
         ...
      }
      ...
```

the strange thing is it did not actually register as a syntax error

the browser appears to have just ignored it

does anybody know what `scope: me,` actually does in this context? just curious

NOTE: this was tested in chrome. and the code is definitely being reached

Comment: It's a statement label.

Comment: a statement label?

Comment: there are uncontrolled jumps in javascript?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) - almost never used javascript feature.

Comment: They're rarely useful but it's a companion feature to `break` and `continue`.

Comment: lol they ripped that syntax off from java

Comment: Related [Javascript goto statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335353/javascript-goto-statement)

Comment: I don't think "ripped off from java" is correct. It's not like java invented any of this.

Comment: i mean using continue and break to reference labels and cutting out goto

Comment: did somebody else do that first?

Comment: i just assumed because i have seen this before (don't remember where) where super obscure features parallel java and i always suspected that they are relics from the time when they were just trying to capitalize on java's popularity like they did by naming the language "JavaScript"

Comment: Well, even if that was the case (unlikely with the forest of languages and theories that existed even before java), it's like saying "there is this language feature that's almost always terribad, but anyone leaving it out ripped off from the first one who left it out". The "ripped off" is adding the wrong message here, as if it was some intellectual property that was copied.

Comment: i yield the point

Comment: Dijkstra wrote `Goto considered harmful` in 1968, Java is about 30 years newer. Javascript isn't a superset of Java, although the name was used to imply it would be friendly enough for Java devs (which was a joke in practicality but the internets was a different place then).

Comment: i know that javascript is not a superset of java. it is an entirely different language however was it not named in such a way to capitalize on the popularity of java in web development at the time?

Comment: so i don't think it is much of a stretch to say that when an obscure feature was developed which is identical in its unusual implementation to java is it unreasonable to say that it was at least "inspired" by java?

Comment: I am unsure whether that's the case, but it may well be, that it was "inspired by java".

Comment: :) not trying to be divisive. it just feels like finding an Easter egg

Comment: I'd say almost all questions i see on SO, that include a labeled statement, added it by accident, and their problem stems from the label. There are real uses for it, and i also have used it in code before, but it's rare. If you like "easter eggs", try `typeof document.all === "undefined" && document.all !== undefined`, in a browser environment.

Comment: I recall JavaScript was used to piggy back on the marketing for Java at the time. And that Scheme is much more important to JavaScript than Java. No idea what other languages had/used labeled breaks at the time, probably have to ask Eich why he included them to know.