# Unable to grasp this javascript snippet function abc(){a:'b'; c:'f'; f:'t'; }; Can someone explain?

Tags: javascript

```
function abc(){
   a:'b'; 
   c:'f'; 
   f:'t'; 
};
```

This snippet does not throw an error in console. I want to understand whats happening with the variables inside the function. Hows it being interpreted by the javascript engine.

Comment: Mmm, that script shows me 7 warnings http://jsbin.com/eraxak/1/edit

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 6):

Those are not variables, they are labels.

They can be used like this (example from [How can I use goto in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751207/how-can-i-use-goto-in-javascript)):

```
LABEL1: do {
  x = x + 2;
  ...
  // JUMP TO THE END OF THE DO-WHILE - A FORWARDS GOTO
  if (x < 100) break LABEL1;
  // JUMP TO THE START OF THE DO WHILE - A BACKWARDS GOTO...
  if (x < 100) continue LABEL1;
} while(0);
```