# How is this not a syntax error? This makes no sense! (javascript)

Tags: javascript

You can have statements on the right hand of an assignment?

```
thing: 123123

thing: "asdfasdf"

thing: {asdf:1234}

thing: (function () {
 return 1
})()

parent: for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  var a = 0
  console.log(a)
  child: while(a < 5) {
    a++
    if (a > 2)
      break parent
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/td951gc7/1/

Comment: no he's not, these aren't properties at all, they are labels for gotos

Answer (score 2):

You are using labels, not assignments

```
i = 0;
a: while(i < 2) {
       j = 0;
       i = (i || 0) +1;
       console.log('hi');
       while(j < 2) {
           j++;
           console.log("there");
           if (i < 1) continue a;
           console.log("hello");
       }
}
```

See also: [How can I use goto in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751207/how-can-i-use-goto-in-javascript)

Comment: Where did `goto` come from? ECMA 262 says that there is no goto statement. Is it new in ECMAScript 6 or 7 or something?

Comment: sorry, forgot, goto is not a statement.  you can use "continue" with a label, which makes it act similar to a goto

Answer (score 2):

`thing:` and `parent:` are not assignments. They are labels (which are a little like targets for GOTOs and are generally only useful when you are dealing with nested loops and want to `break` or `continue` on a specific one of those loops).

- [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)
- [ECMAScript specification for labels](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12)

Answer (score 1):

So you have good answers to WHY this is so - they are labels - but if you would want to have them like assignments, you could only wrap them in an "object":

```
var myClass = {
  thing1: 123123,
  thing2: "asdfasdf",
  thing3: {asdf:1234},
  thing4: function () {
    return 1
  },
  parent: function() {
      for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        var a = 0
        child: while(a < 5) {
        a++
        console.log(a)
        if (a > 2)
          break
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(myClass.thing1);
console.log(myClass.thing2);
console.log(myClass.thing3['asdf']);
console.log(myClass.thing4());

myClass.parent();
```

You can play around here:
http://jsfiddle.net/td951gc7/2/