# HTML JAVASCRIPT goto label?

Tags: javascript, loops, goto, labeled-statements

I need your help, I wish to do a "goto" like "goto" in batch :

```
:loop1
goto loop1
```

but in javascript for html page, all my research are useless...
it can be so usefull to know that !

in my case i need this code because i change a the same 'block of code' many times in different function, and there are to much variable to parse ...
so it can help my a lot

here a simple exemple of what i want to do :

```
    for (var i=0; i < 999; i++) {
        //some code here
        goto go_to_1;
        go_to_2:
        //some code here
        };
    
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        //some different code here
        goto go_to_1;
        go_to_2:
        //some different code here
        };
    
    function mytest () {
        for (var i=0; i < 100; i++) {
            //again some different code here
            goto go_to_1;
            go_to_2:
            //again some different code here
            };
        };


    go_to_1:
    //code here
    //always the same code here ,i change it many times
    temp = "library"+i+"";
    //code here 
    goto go_to_2;
```

is that possible?
how use the "goto" function in javascript?

Comment: Generally speaking goTo is a bad practice, you should find a better way to achieve what you are doing

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's no `goto` in javascript. See the linked answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has NO goto statement, you can only use labels with the break or continue.

You can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.

```js
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         continue loop1;
      }
      log.innerHTML += ('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j + "<br/>");
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="log"> </div>
```

Please Take a look at these:

[mozilla developers - js label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

[stackoverflow - js label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9751229/3091563)