# Is there any way to run old versions of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was any way for me to run older versions of javascript in the web browser!
I have apps that require ECMAScript 3 that broke and I was wondering if there was anyway to run older versions without a polyfill library!

Comment: JavaScript (ES) engines are built into the browsers -- if you want to find a specific engine, you'll have to find a browser that implemented it (digging up old Internet Explorers).  However, very few things are depreciated -- so you can program in an older style and it should still be valid.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my grammer! I am bad at spelling and I am very young (won’t say exact age so I can keep my account) but around if you get the picture 6th to 8th grade!

Comment: You should not be using goto.  That kind of coding leads to all kinds of errors in your code that are hard to trace... I would STRONGLY recommend learning the "new" syntax (if, for, while, etc.) over using goto

Comment: @Jonathan Rys Ok!! I’ll try learning that syntax!! I use w3schools.com which doesn’t have the best teaching method do you know any good sites or books for learning ECMAScript 5/6?

Comment: Here's a joke post about using goto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751207/how-can-i-use-goto-in-javascript

Comment: @JacobMorris https://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, those were the OP's words I was quoting.  In fact that syntax predates JavaScript by a few decades.  I believe Djikstra came up with structured programming.

Comment: @JacobMorris great start: https://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While it works fine, I want it to use ECMAScript 3 for functions like goto and such

JavaScript does not have, and has never had, `goto`.

> and I dislike using the newer keywords.

Whatever you mean by "newer keywords", if you dislike using them, then don't use them.

> Does anyone know of a way to use older ECMAScript/JavaScript versions?

Yes, use any current ES/JS version, since they are all completely backward compatible for all practical purposes.

Comment: Interesting, https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf `ECMAScript has no goto statement`, it was only a future reserved keyword.

Comment: Holy moly! What happened to your reputation points?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I deleted my account due to a moderator who was acting dictatorially in a dispute on Meta. Now I hang out when I really don't have anything better to do, which is almost never.

Comment: That sucks! Sorry to hear.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Babel](http://babeljs.io/), it's a traspiler of Js to Js, you can set the enter version and the out version and it's easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks very much!!! I will look into it!

Comment: Which enter or out version would I set in order to use `goto`?